# Best Practice to storing server logs and front end log in mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, logging, sails.js

I have an api which stores all the logs of the server every seconds. This api stores all the logs which are recorded in the server every seconds.

To track record of the front end javascript. This api is called every seconds which store all the activity which is happening on the front side and is saved in the mysql database.

Now application is scaling and number of request is increasing day by day and there is lots of burden on the server which is slowing the application.

So what should be industry best practice to store logs in database when huge amount of data is coming and number of request is increasing?

I don't want to use any third party logging mechanism for this.

So, to all experienced programmers - what's your experience with storing logs? Any advice?

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: You really should look at pendo.io website for the level of detail you are storing.  An external service will allow you to manage your business requirements rather than being forever dealing with log scaling issues mingled with real business transactions that produce income for your organization.  My previous comment has asked for data for workload analysis of your current MySQL instance.